# Is the small tag a structural or strictly styling element?

Tags: html

Is `<small>` normally used as a *purely* styling element, or can it be used as a structural element as well? In other words, in an HTML flow, which is correct:

```
<p><small>I am a paragraph of small text</small></p>
```

or

```
<small>I am a snippet of small text, only bound by small and not by any other text-tag</small>
```

Comment: Probably should be used as you would a `strong` tag - http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-small-element

Comment: @ialarmedalien - from the above spec: `The small element represents side comments such as small print.` I think that can be counted as a characteristic.  And yes I know you you can have strong small text

Comment: @ialarmedalien The question isn't about assistive devices, it's whether the small tag is structural or styling only and the answer is that it does have some structural importance as it is used to mark sections like disclaimers and other such small print, and should not be used over extended spans of text - which if it were a styling element only, would be allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HTML 4's definition of `small`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html#h-15.2.1) is extremely vague:

> **SMALL:** Renders text in a "small" font.

I can't tell if this is meant to be presentational, or something else. Any text could potentially be rendered in a small font regardless of whether this small font carries any meaning at all. It seems like a cheap alternative to `<span style="font-size: smaller">` in CSS.

[HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-small-element), on the other hand, says that `small` represents [fine print](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine_print), which has a very specific meaning. Fine print refers to things like disclaimers or copyrights, which are *usually* displayed in a small font in virtually all typographic settings. For example:

```
<p>Best of all, it's completely free!*</p>
<p><small>* Some features may require a free account.</small></p>
```

It does not refer to just any text that happens to be displayed in a small font; for that, you should style the text using CSS instead, as that use case would be considered purely presentational.

As to whether `small` can be used on its own, note that HTML5 classifies it as phrasing content, which means it may appear anywhere that phrasing content is accepted. A `p` element accepts phrasing content, and a `footer` element accepts either flow content, phrasing content, or a mix of both. Let's say you had a footer element that consisted only of a single run of fine print. Either of these is OK:

```
<footer>
  <p><small>Fine print.</small></p>
</footer>

<footer>
  <small>Fine print.</small>
</footer>
```

In terms of CSS, most phrasing content elements are rendered as `display: inline`.

Comment: purely pedantic point, but `small` encompasses side comments and fine print - there is not a specific semantic meaning to text in a `small` tag.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you complied to either of my possible answers (which I fine, of course). From your explanation and your example it seems that you would rather use `small` as a stylistic tag, which - in HTML5 at least - ought to be used for semantic purposes. However, does that mean that it can be used as a structural element as well, consisting as an element in itself (i.e. without the wrapping `p`-tags)?

Answer (score 0):

Both are "correct" - if correct means *valid*.

> Although the `<small>` element, like the `<b>` and `<i>` elements, may be
>   perceived to violate the principle of separation between structure and
>   presentation, all three are valid in HTML5. Authors are encouraged to
>   use their best judgement when determining whether to use `<small>` or
>   CSS.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/small

Comment: Given the context of the question, it should be pretty obvious what "correct" really means.